# Cannot restart neo4j with error "No space left on device"

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, ubuntu-16.04

We have Neo4j 3.3.5 community version running on an Ubuntu 16.04.4 TLS and it crashed while we were creating relationships between certain nodes. 
The relationships are made with at python program using the py2neo module. When the process crashed, the following error was produced by py2neo:
*[2018-07-06 15:47:33] The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details.*
*[2018-07-06 15:47:33] [Errno 24] Too many open files*
The latter was printed 1830 times.
The error shown in the neo4j log file is *"device out of space"*. Then we cleared some space in the disk, now there are more than 3.5 GB available.

The problem we are how having is that we cannot restart neo4j any more. 
The first error was: 
*"Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)".*
For this, we found a solution online that suggested to kill the java process connected to "org.neo4j.server". However, killing these processes did not help and we still cannot start the server with the command: 
'''sudo service neo4j start'''
It now produces the following error: 
*..."java.io.IOException: No space left on device". *
But when we check the disk there is more than enough space and Inodes seems alright. 
Another suggestion is to re-instal the database. However, we would like to understand what happened before we take such a drastic step in order to prevent it from happening again.

Any ideas and/or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question : Are you sure that the left space is on the good partitioni ( see it with `df -h`) ? And can you post the debug.log file when you start the server ?

Comment: Hello Logisima, Thanks for your comment. My disk usage is as follows: <br/> ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-146:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M  5.5M  390M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  4.3G  3.5G  55% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000

Comment: Apologies for the format above, I am new to Stackoverflow and have yet to figure out how to format a comment.

Comment: OT: Since this question is on google first page searching for No space left error, I would like to mention that in can also mean problem in Docker environment - checking allowed disk space for Docker or calling `docker system prune --volumes` could help.